# what is the fundamental solution for Error in knn: too many ties in knn

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, linear-regression

Hope this finds you well, I am applying Knn model in the data landsat, and I have this error:

```
Error in knn(learn[, -1], test[, -1], learn[, 1], k = 1) : 
  too many ties in knn.
```

however I reduce the number of neighborhood to 1. could any one help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From an algorithmic standpoint, this likely means that there are too many neighbors equidistant to the target point, such that the algorithm cannot choose only k of them.  This often happens when you have a discrete distance function.

Another problem that arises sometimes is when the classification is discrete classes, and the algorithm cannot handle ties properly.  However, reducing K to 1, which you've done, guarantees that you don't have that problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your notes but I do that , k=1, and the problem still the same.

Comment: I know; my intent was to acknowledge that the second item is not your problem.  Fixing my wording.